# Filtering based on catagories (string) empty data frame - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, data-wrangling

I have dataframe like this;

```
    bins      A        C    D
1.0 -  2.0    1.32    0.5   7
4.0 -  5.0    4.044   0.5   20
5.0 -  6.0    5.86    0.5   29
5.0 -  6.0    8.06    0.5   30
6.0 -  7.0    6.76    0.5   34
8.0 -  9.0    11.96   0.5   44
11.0 -  12.0  12.00   0.2   24
11.0 -  12.0  12.00   0.2   24
```

I want to get rid of the all rows where bins are below 11.0 -  12.0

I tried

```
df_.loc[df['bins'] > '11.0 - 12.0']
  
df.query(bins > '11.0 - 12.0')
```

but none of this is working as dont get any value back

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: it won't work above solution because you are using greater than in the string datatype.

Comment: Is there one space or 2 spaces after the hyphen ?   Your sample data have 2 while your code has one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
>>> x = df['bins'].str.split('\s+-\s+', expand=True).astype(float)
>>> df[x[0].ge(11) & x[1].ge(12)]
          bins     A    C   D
6  11.0 - 12.0  12.0  0.2  24
7  11.0 - 12.0  12.0  0.2  24
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to locate the first row index of `bins` in that value, then `.loc` from that index onwards:

```
df.loc[df.index[df['bins'] == '11.0 - 12.0'][0]: ]
```

Result:

```
          bins     A    C   D
6  11.0 - 12.0  12.0  0.2  24
7  11.0 - 12.0  12.0  0.2  24
```